# iOS: Unable to set LaunchImage

Tags: ios

I have LaunchImage.png file in my iPhone Xcode 5.1 project. I have added LaunchImage.png in app .plist file. I have drag and dropped this file in LaunchImage image xcassets. But, still it is throwing error as when build xcode project

```
/Users/MyApplication/Images.xcassets: The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content.
```

What could be the reason, please help!

Thank yoU!

Comment: What's the format of your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is due to the dimension of the image. Before the error, there is a warning message also check out that .

From [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

> Create launch images in different sizes for different devices. Launch
>   images for all devices must include the status bar region. Create
>   launch images in the following sizes:
>
> For iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation):
>
> 640 x 1136 pixels For other iPhone and iPod touch devices:
>
> 640 x 960 pixels 320 x 480 pixels (standard resolution) For iPad
>   portrait:
>
> 1536 x 2048 pixels 768 x 1024 pixels (standard resolution) For iPad
>   landscape:
>
> 2048 x 1536 pixels 1024 x 768 pixels (standard resolution)

Comment: I dont' have iPhone 5. I have iPhone 4 and 3GS.

Comment: Check the remaining for all

Comment: what's the dimension of image, which you'r added?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `LaunchImage.png` as a `Default.png` and also drag and dropped this file in LaunchImage image xcassets.